# ASP.NET Public Variable at Code Behind is not accesible in .aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is a simple example of what is happening here.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="base._default1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <% Response.Write(sName) %>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and the code behind default.aspx.vb

```
Public Class _default1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public sName As String = "Jimmy"

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

the error is

BC30451 'sName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    base    C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\base\base\teste\default.aspx   12

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue is your class `_default1` is not marked as `partial` class.

It should rather be

```
Public partial Class _default1
      Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

One more point is that your page directive has the property `AutoEventWireup="false"` and with that the way you have your page events mapped right now will not work. So set it to true rather `AutoEventWireup="true"`

Your `@Page` directive is total weird as can be seen below.

```
<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="base._default1" %>
```

To summarize; below are the issues you should take care off

1. mark the class `partial`
2. set `AutoEventWireup="true"`
3. change `CodeBehind` property to `CodeBehind="default1.aspx.vb"`
4. Change your `Inherits` property to `Inherits="your_namespace._default1"`

Comment: Yeah and my bad that was not the issue at all. See edit in answer.

Comment: @JuanPhotizo, consider accepting he answer then by clicking the check button.